# Circle detection via Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I am writing a matlab code that takes in a photo and detects the circular object. After using some filters, I got below image.

[image]

To detect circular object(it is not a perfect circle), I tried to apply [Hough Transform](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4985-circle-detection-via-standard-hough-transform/content//houghcircle.m) passing different values of radius and threshold, but it couldn't detect properly. Why this happens? Is it about shape of object or background of image?

Also is it possible to detect same object at the following image using Hough Transform?

[image]

Edge of circular object seems by human eye, but I am not sure that background can be eliminated from image completely via Hough Transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [imfindcircles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) in the Image Processing Toolbox. Using morphology to fill in the circle and cranking up sensitivity may help:

```
im = imread('pattern.jpg');
im2 = rgb2gray(im(100:end-100, 100:end-100, :));
im3 = im2bw(im2, 0.1);
im4 = imclose(im3, strel('disk', 4, 4));
im5 = imfill(im4, 'holes');
imshow(im5);
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(im5, [180, 200], 'Sensitivity', .99);
viscircles(centers, radii);
```

[image]

Comment: @user3319676 - You should make that clear next time.  You did not mention the fact that you used the Circular Hough Transform.  You gave reference to a script on MATLAB FEX, which is **not** `imfindcircles`.

Comment: I've used your solution for second image without 'imfill' and 'imclose', it worked.